# Alternating row style in Gridview

Tags: aspxgridview

Is it possible to apply alternating row style in gridview column level .
I have rowspan for gridview column if the values are equal . I dont alternating row style to be applied for first 2 columns alone. Can anyone help me in achieving this.

Comment: was my answer helpful for you?

Comment: good good ) very good )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ASPxGridView.Styles.AlternatingRow.Enabled`

Answer (score 0):

I used `GridName.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "grdViewAltRow";` in the c# code behind just before

```
GridName.Datasource = dataTable;
GridName.DataBind();
```

With

```
<style>
.grdViewAltRow {
            background-color:#E8E8FF;
        }
</stye>
```